# Why ionic serve is showing Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When I use the command `Ionic serve`, my project loads in the browser and shows the following errors in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null(…)
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
>
> GET http://localhost:8100/ net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

How to fix it?

Comment: add your code here. Also, let us know what have you tried so far to debug and what is not working ?

Comment: Basically from reading the error it seems that you're trying to access innerHTML of an element which is undefined. But for detecting where exactly this is happening I cometely agree with the first comment - for being able to detect the error please add all the missing details to your question.

Comment: This cleanup makes the question easier to read.  The relevant javascript and HTML code should be added, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set innerHTML to either undefined variable or unassigned variable.

Please cross check